# How to remove eventlistener while passing the data to the listener using bind?

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I am adding an event listener and then trying to remove it as shown:

### Scenario-1

```
class A{
function A(){
   elem.addEventListener('mouseover',this.onMouseOver);
   elem.addEventListener('mouseout',this.onMouseOut);
}

function B(){
   elem.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.onMouseOut);
}

function onMouseOver(){

}
function onMouseOut(){
  console.log('-------------------------------mouse out-------------');
}
}
```

In the above scenario my listener is getting removed but it is not getting removed when I bind some value as :

### Scenario-2

```
class A{
function A(){
   elem.addEventListener('mouseover',this.onMouseOver);
   elem.addEventListener('mouseout',this.onMouseOut.bind(null,"A"));
}

function B(){
   elem.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.onMouseOut.bind(null,"A"));
}

function onMouseOver=()=>{

}
function onMouseOut=(name:string,e:any)=>{
  console.log('-------------------------------mouse out-------------'+name);
}
}
```

Why event listener is getting removed in Scenario-1 and not in Scenario-2 ? How do I bind the value like Scenario-2 so that it will remove as well as add event listener ??

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the _exact_ same function reference to remove an event handler again, that was used when it was attached. `bind` creates a new function instance each time. You need to store the reference to this into a variable, so that you can refer to the _same_ instance again when you want to remove it.

Comment: The second example is not valid JavaScript (or TypeScript) and it's unclear how all the functions are related and what you expect `this` to refer to in `A` and `B`.

Comment: @CBroe How do I store this to a reference variable when it is again used by this ?

Comment: `var something = this.onMouseOut.bind(null,"A");` And then you use just `something` in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`

Comment: @CBroe I already tried this , but it is not working .

Comment: “Not working” as a problem description doesn’t help anyone, you need to give us a proper one. Also edit your question to show your updated code please.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, but could you give an example for the same ?

Comment: You can [take a look at the wrapper](https://jsfiddle.net/ehvbto3a/). It's a simplified version from the one in my toolbox. I'm not sure, how well it can be translated to TypeScript, since it utilizes JavaScript's dynamic nature.

Comment: The wrapper has an ability to remove listeners set with anonymous functions too. Only that you can't pass data in a separate arguments with that wrapper. Instead, include the data into the object `this` refers.

Answer (score 0):

From the code and the usage of `this`, I assume `this` to be a object structure where `this` binds the functions together in a common context.

```
function A(){
   this.mouseOutFunctionImpl = this.onMouseOut.bind(null,"A");
   elem.addEventListener('mouseover',this.onMouseOver);
   elem.addEventListener('mouseout',this.mouseOutFunctionImpl);
}

function B(){
   elem.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.mouseOutFunctionImpl);
}

function onMouseOver=()=>{

}
function onMouseOut=(name:string,e:any)=>{
  console.log('-------------------------------mouse out-------------'+name);
}
```